# How to search/traverse for specific key in dict for updating value in python?

Tags: python

Using python 2.x, suppose I have the following:

```
target = {'field':'occupation', 'value':'Sanitation Specialist'}

thedict = {'name:':'Wilson','hobbies':['Sports', 'Basketball','Volleyball'], 'job':{
'occupation': 'Janitor',
'years_worked': 5,
'locations': {
'loc_name': 'CompanyA',
'loc_alias': 'The Finest Company',
 },
 'married': 'Yes'
 'children': 5
}};
```

How to create a function such that I can replace the value in the nested field `CnestedA` with `value` without hardcoding the fact that the `CnestedA` field is actually nested in `fieldC` (i.e. `thedict['job']['occupation']`? The function should take a "target" object like above, and a `thedict` to be updated. Note that if the 'target' object stayed the same, but in the `dict`, `occupation` happened to be an immediate key in thedict, (i.e. `thedict['occupation']`), the function would still work. If it doesnt find the `field`, then nothing happens to `thedict`.

Comment: This is not an efficient way to organize your data; if you have to search the values for the field you're looking for, you lose most of the benefits of having a dict at all.

Comment: In your example data, the name `'CnestedA'` encodes the fact that the field is nested in `'fieldC'`. Will this be the case in your real data?

Comment: No, the fields could be something completely different that would not suggest that it is nested. Updated with a more practical example.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a recursive search algorithm, but it'd be inefficient. Instead, it'd be a better idea to either reorganize your data or create an auxiliary data structure that records where each field is.

To reorganize your data for efficient lookup, you'd de-nest your dict, moving all keys to the top-level dict. If you need information previously encoded in the path to the key, put that into the value. Then, to perform an update, you'd use

```
denested_dict[key] = value
```

or

```
denested_dict[key].data = value
```

if you created some sort of value object with a `data` field for what used to be the value and a `path` field to record the old path.

If it's inconvenient to reorganize your data, you can instead create a dict that maps each key to the dict that has that key. Then, to update an arbitrarily nested key, you'd use the new dict to look up the dict to update and update that.

```
index_dict[key][key] = value
```